# WAF: Conflict between MinGW (GCC) and MSVC 2012

Tags: visual-c++, build, mingw, configure, waf

I've just run into misery with WAF. I use MinGW-w64 exclusively to build stuff. But, recently, I've installed MSVC 2012 because sometimes it is required to build various small utilities which have some issues when building with MinGW.

WAF encourages not to hard-code the compiler choice into `wscript`, but rather select it from the command line which sounds very reasonable and I'm with that philosophy in this case. So the `wscript` should look like this (forget about `boost`):

```
def options(ctx):
    ctx.load(('compiler_cxx', 'boost'))


def configure(ctx):
    ctx.load(('compiler_cxx', 'boost'))
    ctx.check_boost()
```

Then one simply types in the command line:

```
waf --boost-includes=D:/Applications/Boost/include --check-cxx-compiler=gxx configure build
```

The `--check-cxx-compiler=gxx` forces WAF to look for MinGW in the first place since by default on Windows WAF prefers MSVC first.

**NOTE:** MinGW-w64 is in the `PATH`, MSVC is not, but WAF can still find it due to registry I guess.

So, then WAF gives this in the configuration output (which means everything is cool):

```
Checking for 'gxx' (c++ compiler)        : D:\Applications\MinGW-w64\bin\g++.exe
```

Then it starts building, and what I get is this long spam:

```
Build failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Applications\WAF\waf-1.7.8-77e2cdd38ea2930f982e3aabf335fdb7\waflib\Task.py", line 123, in process
    ret=self.run()
  File "D:\Applications\WAF\waf-1.7.8-77e2cdd38ea2930f982e3aabf335fdb7\waflib\Task.py", line 47, in run
    return m1(self)
  File "D:\Applications\WAF\waf-1.7.8-77e2cdd38ea2930f982e3aabf335fdb7\waflib\Task.py", line 47, in run
    return m1(self)
  File "<string>", line 28, in f
  File "D:\Applications\WAF\waf-1.7.8-77e2cdd38ea2930f982e3aabf335fdb7\waflib\Tools\msvc.py", line 685, in exec_command_msvc
    return self.exec_command_nomsvc(*k,**kw)

    ... (repeated thousands of times)

  File "D:\Applications\WAF\waf-1.7.8-77e2cdd38ea2930f982e3aabf335fdb7\waflib\Tools\msvc.py", line 685, in exec_command_msvc
    return self.exec_command_nomsvc(*k,**kw)
File "D:\Applications\WAF\waf-1.7.8-77e2cdd38ea2930f982e3aabf335fdb7\waflib\Tools\msvc.py", line 684, in exec_command_msvc
    if self.env['CC_NAME']!='msvc':
  File "D:\Applications\WAF\waf-1.7.8-77e2cdd38ea2930f982e3aabf335fdb7\waflib\ConfigSet.py", line 35, in __getitem__
    self=self.parent
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

How should MSVC be involved in this build process?! - I have no idea. But anyway, here comes the most interesting part. Lets break recommendations and hard-code GCC to be our choice in the `wscript`:

```
def options(ctx):
    ctx.load(('boost'))


def configure(ctx):
    ctx.load(('gxx', 'boost'))
    ctx.check_boost()
```

Then we invoke:

```
waf --boost-includes=D:/Applications/Boost/include configure build
```

And see in the configuration output:

```
Checking for program g++,c++             : D:\Applications\MinGW-w64\bin\g++.exe
Checking for program ar                  : D:\Applications\MinGW-w64\bin\ar.exe
```

**NOTE:** Noticed how the output has changed? This is already a mystery to me because the `cxx_compiler` tool (used in the previous case) itself calls `ctx.load('gxx')` behind the scenes. So how could these 2 outputs be different in these 2 cases?

Then WAF starts building and there you go:

```
'build' finished successfully (1.155s)
```

Cool right? :) Let me know what you guys think, and hopefully someone has already encountered this.

**Starring**

WAF 1.7.8

MinGW-w64 (GCC 4.7.2)

MSVC 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a bug report to Thomas Nagy, and he found out that it was due to one of the recent  patches. Reverting this patch fixed the issue. See these 2 issues for more details:

- [Issue 1243](http://code.google.com/p/waf/issues/detail?id=1243)
- [Issue 1237](http://code.google.com/p/waf/issues/detail?id=1237)